# Proof some module is direct sum by its submodules.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules, $f\colon M \to N$, $g\colon N \to M$ $R$-module homomorphisms such that $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y \in N$. Show that $M$ is direct sum by  $\mathrm{ker} f$ and $\mathrm{im} g$.

I can't understand how to use R-module homomorphism in this question.What's the use of module homorphism.

Comment: this might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029629/direct-summand-of-modules-proof/1029739

Comment: you want to say the map f is surjective,yes?

Comment: yes!! $fg$ surjective implies $f$ is surjective.

Comment: We also have $g$ injective since $fg$ is. Actually $gf$ is an idempotent endomorphism of $M$, and $\DeclareMathOperator\id{id}\,\,\id_M -gf$ is the orthogonal idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

- For $m ∈ M$ look at $m - g(f(m))$.
- For $m ∈ \operatorname{ker} f ∩ \operatorname{img} g$, write $m = g(n)$ for some $n ∈ N$.